# Applying constructor's single arg interface as properties on the class

Tags: typescript

I have a class `Example` it's constructor takes one argument `props` which is an object interface.

I am looking for a way to set all of the properties of the `Props` interface as properties of `Example` with as little duplication as possible.

```
interface Props {
  alpha: boolean,
  beta: boolean,
  gamma: boolean,
}

class Example {
  constructor (props: Props) {}
}
```

Things I've tried:

- Using `public` argument flag allows `this.props.alpha`
- Using `implements Props`
- Using a `for in` loop in the constructor (see below)
- Using `Object.assign(this, props)` in the constructor

```
for (const key in props) {
  this[key] = props[key];
}
```

To be clear, I don't want to have to do this:

```
interface Props {
  alpha: boolean,
  beta: boolean,
  gamma: boolean,
}

class Example {
  alpha: boolean,
  beta: boolean,
  gamma: boolean,
  constructor (props: Props) {
    this.alpha = props.alpha
    this.beta = props.beta
    this.gamma = props.gamma
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for a combination of the `Object.assign` technique you've mentioned and declaration merging.

```
interface Props {
  alpha: boolean;
  beta: boolean;
  gamma: boolean;
}

interface Example extends Props { }
class Example {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    Object.assign(this, props);
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOyDeAUMsnADZYAWcAXMgEYYZkRwgA0xDEYtDTLNpxIBzOAFtxfRs1YdCAX0KhIsRCgCiADwlYWyCFsggAJnnTY8+ZEoRk4OPNt36iJBBhA4wUAK4IwDCgACixMXDoLXABKAi4SAHl6ACsIAIA6BxxgERBgsEpgHHZkMMtogG4uJQUgA)

In the above code, the type `Example` results from two declarations, `class Example` and `interface Example`, which are merged together as a single type.

Within any scope, an arbitrary number of interface and zero or one class declarations having the same name merge into a single type containing all of their respective members.